# Reload a table view without affecting the countdown timer in the cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITableView` called `itemDisplayTable`. Each cell inside it has a countdown timer and a text field. I want the textfield to be updated with the data from the server whenever there is a change in value. So I reload the entire table view every second using `NSTimer`.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var call = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("refresh"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)      
}

func refresh() {
  // GET request from the server
  itemDisplayTable.reloadData()
}
```

Table view code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if (tableView.tag == 1)
    {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("collectionCell") as! CollectionCell

    cell.category.text = categoryName1[indexPath.row]
    setUpScrollView(cell.scrollView,categoryname: categoryName1[indexPath.row])
    return cell
    }
    else
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("categoryName") as! CategoryTableViewCell
        cell.categoryImage .image = UIImage(named: categoryImage[indexPath.row])
        cell.categoryName.text = itemname[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}

 func setUpScrollView(scroll : UIScrollView ,categoryname:NSString ){
      scroll.subviews.map{ $0.removeFromSuperview() }

    items = self.retriveStatus(categoryname as String)

        for item in items {

        let array = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("collectionView", owner: self, options: nil) as NSArray
                    let view = array.objectAtIndex(0) as! ItemDisplayView

                   view.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(190 * items.indexOf(item)!)+20, 0, 170 , 250)
                    view.layer.borderColor=UIColor(red: 231.0/255, green: 231.0/255, blue: 231.0/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
                    view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0


            if item.offerstatus == "active" {
                view.invalidateTimer()
                view.showOfferTime(item.itemExpiryDate!)
            }

            view.currentBidPrice.text = item.currentBidPrice                // my text field data

                    scroll.addSubview(view)
        }

     scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: (190 * items.count)+20, height: 250)

    }
}
```

Class for the Cell elements of the tableView:

```
  class ItemDisplayView: UIView {

   @IBOutlet weak var currentBidPrice: UILabel!

   @IBOutlet var timerLabel: UILabel!


   func showOfferTime(dString:NSString) -> Void {

    offerTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target:       
  self, selector: #selector(self.converDatetoTime(_:)),  
  userInfo:dString, repeats: true)

}

func invalidateTimer() -> Void {

    offerTimer.invalidate()

}

func converDatetoTime(timer:NSTimer) -> Void {

    let dString = timer.userInfo
    let dateAsString = dString
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy, HH:mm:ss"
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateAsString as! String)
    timerLabel.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(date!.timeIntervalSinceDate(NSDate())) as String

}

func stringFromTimeInterval(interval:NSTimeInterval) -> NSString {

    let ti = NSInteger(interval)

    //let ms = Int((interval % 1) * 1000)

    let seconds = ti % 60
    let minutes = (ti / 60) % 60
    let hours = (ti / 3600)

    if interval>0 {
        return NSString(format: "%0.2d:%0.2d:%0.2d",hours,minutes,seconds)
    } else {
        return "00:00:00"
    }
}
```

**Problem** : The textfield is getting updated perfectly but since the tableView is getting reloaded every second, the countdown timer appears to be "00:00:00" though it is running actively.

Is there any way to update or reload the textfield alone inside a cell or to avoid the countdown timer showing "00:00:00".

Comment: you are loading the value of your countDown timer from where?

Comment: I have a calendar button and I set the value of countdown timer with that. I only want the textfield value to be updated from the server.

Comment: show the `cellForRowAtIndex` code

Comment: @Abiranjan I think you are not maintaining any model for table cells. Modelling will solve your problem. Just update your textfield value and keep countdown as it is..

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        if (tableView.tag == 1)
        {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("collectionCell") as! CollectionCell
        
        cell.category.text = categoryName1[indexPath.row]
        setUpScrollView(cell.scrollView,categoryname: categoryName1[indexPath.row])
        return cell
        }
}

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari : that is what my question is.. How to update my textfield alone without affecting the countdown. I am a beginner.

Comment: Still incomplete info. What is `setUpScrollView` method doing. Frame the question properly again and dont write code in comments. Edit question details

Comment: please find the edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I want the textfield to be updated with the data from the server whenever there is a change in value. So I reload the entire table view every second using NSTimer.

Reloading an entire tableView is not the way to do this; it's slow especially if you have a large table. Is there a way you can open a socket to listen to changes from your server and only update the specific cells that changed when the server sends a change? You can reload specific cells using the following, where `indexPathsArray` is an array of NSIndexPaths pointing to any cells that need to be refreshed:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPathsArray, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

2. Is there any way to update or reload the textfield alone inside a cell or to avoid the countdown timer showing "00:00:00".

I suggest maintaining a data model for your UITableView. Right now it sounds like the state of your data is only kept in the tableView's cells. So when you refresh your tableView every second, you are throwing out the current state of your data.

You need to keep an array of your data outside the tableView. It would be helpful to keep all data relevant to a single cell together using a struct so you do not have to maintain multiple data arrays. Maybe you'd have something similar to this:

```
struct CategoryElement {
  var name: String  // category's name
  var imageName: String // category's image name
  var timer: NSTimer // the current timer for that cell item
  var value: String // the text field value ?
}
```

(There may be more/less data you want to keep in here, but I'm not 100% sure what you're doing from your question.)

Then your view controller will have a dataModel array which contains all the information for all your tableView cells: `var dataModel: [CategoryElement]`.

Now, in `func tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you will create the cell using the information from your data model. Since the timer is kept in your dataModel array, you'll be able to get the current time and refreshing the tableView will not reset your timer.

```
if (tableView.tag == 1)
{
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("collectionCell") as! CollectionCell

  cell.category.text = dataModel[indexPath.row].name
  setUpScrollView(cell.scrollView,categoryname: dataModel[indexPath.row].name)
  return cell
}
```

Then in your `setUpScrollView:categoryname` function, you should not invalidate the timer unless the item's status changes. Instead, the ItemDisplayView's timer should be assigned `dataModel[indexPath.row].timer`. Anytime you need to stop or reset the timer, you must change it through the data model at `dataModel[indexPath.row].timer`.

Basically, your `func tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` should not be updating any data in your data model. It should just be displaying it. Then when you get updates from the server, you update your dataModel array. To SHOW these changes on the screen, you can refresh the entire table (though again, it would be more efficient to only update the cells that have changed).

I hope this gives you some guidance on how to resolve your problems.

Comment: Hurray it works !! I created the data model but still didn't help. Instead of reloading every second I reloaded the table only when there is a change in data and it worked. Thanks though